# Kdenlive won't update on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kde, video-editor, kdenlive

When i install kdenlive, i get version 15.12.13. I have added the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
```

I've updated and upgraded in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But it does not upgrade kdenlive. The software updater does not give an update either.

Comment: It seems the daily app image from the developer is the only option for installing the latest version, but when i download the app image and run it, as instructed, it just runs the program, not an install. Does anyone know how to use the app image to update or reinstall a newer version?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not receiving any updates because you're already on the latest version of `kdenlive` that was packaged for Xenial.

I looked at the [`kdenlive-stable` repository](https://launchpad.net/~kdenlive/+archive/ubuntu/kdenlive-stable) and it looks like they're only packaging updates for Cosmic (now EOL), Disco, and Eoan.

However, I also saw on the developers' website that [they publish a daily AppImage](https://kdenlive.org/en/download/).

So, if you want the latest and greatest, you can upgrade to Disco or Eoan, or alternatively, install `kdenlive` via their AppImage.

Comment: I have tried the app image route. All i seem to get is a stand alone program and not and install when i run the app image. And that would have been okay but it always crashed upon rendering. I know i did it before, but i haven't a clue how. Ver. 15 is so terrible and crashy and i had been using 16 or 17 on my old computer. Any tips on using the app image to install the version instead of just running from the folder? @cpk